# Mongoose .populate random

Tags: javascript, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

Its possible to 'populate random' ?

**Example**

```
.populate({
    path: 'path',
    options: {limit: 2}
});
```

*"Example"* always return the same 2 items. Always the last 2 items in the array.
Is it possible to return a random item using `.populate()`? How can it be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user `javascript`' `Math.random` and `Math.floor`

> The random() method returns a random number from 0 (inclusive) up to
>   but not including 1 (exclusive).

more details and examples : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp

so to have a random limit between `1` and `20` :

```
var myLimit = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1) + 1);

.populate({
    path: 'path',
    options: {limit: myLimit}
});
```

**EDIT**

if you want to return `2` random items each time, use `skip` :

```
var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1) + 1);

.populate({
    path: 'path',
    options: {limit: 2, skip:myRandom}
});
```

but this will pick two random records among the first `20` , to be more accurate you need to count all records and then generate a random number between 1 and that count :

```
yourModel.count({}, function( err, count){

    var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (count - 1) + 1);

    // your old code ..
    .populate({
        path: 'path',
        options: {limit: 2, skip:myRandom}
    }); 
})
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont want to change the limit, I want it to be 2, the problem is that it always return only the same 2 items

Comment: I want to do something like $sample, that always return random items. Is it possible to return random items using populate ?